# Most common term for hanfu in Cantonese?

Tags: difference, word, cantonese

What is the most common term for *hanfu* (as in 'Hanfu movement'), i.e. modern clothing inspired by historical costumes? Is 漢服 (or 漢裝) used in spoken Cantonese, or maybe it is more of a Mandarin/Written Chinese word? Are the words 唐服 or 唐裝 more common in modern Cantonese? Is there any difference between them in meaning or usage?

Answer (score 1):

I think the most commonly used are:

漢服 - Mandarin [hànfú] Cantonese [hon3 fuk6]

唐装 - Mandarin [tángzhuāng] Cantonese [tong4 zong1]

Note that "漢", "唐" are two different dynasties, each has its own dressing style that is wildly imitated by the clothing stylists from time to time.

Answer (score 0):

> 漢服 (Hanfu) is a term used by Cantonese and Mandarin

In the narrow sense, it refers to 漢朝服裝 (costumes from the Han Dynasty)

In the broad sense, it refers to 漢民族服裝 (The Han Chinese periods clothing) also known as 古裝 (ancient dresses), and it is most of the Hanfu movement participants' idea of 漢服, which means the clothing of the Tang, Song, and Ming dynasties are also Hanfu.

漢朝服裝 (Han Dynasty clothing)

[image: 漢朝服裝]

唐朝服裝 (Tang Dynasty clothing)

[image: 唐朝服裝]

宋朝服裝 (Song Dynasty clothing)

[image: 宋朝服裝]

明朝服裝 (Ming Dynasty clothing)

[image: 明朝服裝]

清朝 (The Qing Dynasty) was not ruled by Han Chinese, therefore, the costumes of The Qing Dynasty are not considered 漢服, but 清裝 (Qing Dynasty clothing)

清裝 (Qing Dynasty clothing)

[image: 清朝服裝]

> 唐裝, a term used by Cantonese

It refers to Chinese traditional costumes in the early Republic of China, as opposed to 洋服 (Westen costumes)

洋服 (Westen clothing) on the left, 唐裝(Chinese traditional clothing)  on the right

[image: 洋服, 唐裝]

*元朝(The Yuan Dynasty) lasted less than 90 years, Yuan Dynasty Chinese clothing was similar to Song's*

*Basically, all period costumes except for Qing Dynasty clothing are called 漢服/ 古裝*